# Stow does not respect .stow-local-ignore

Tags: stow

Within package `a`, I have directory `.config/c/d`. I want stow to ignore `d`, while stowing everything else.

So, I first did `stow -D a -t ~`, verifying that `c` was no longer in `~/.config`. Then, I added to the `.stow-local-ignore` in `a` this line:

`\.config/c/d`

I then did `stow a -t ~`. However, when I check `~/.config`, I see a symlink `c`, with `d` inside.

I noticed that if the line was just `\.config/c`, `c` isn't symlinked in `.config`.

This does work if I use `--no-folding`.